# laravel optional parameter routing

Tags: laravel

I've got a question about the laravel routing.
If you try to do like this:

```
Route::get('users/{id?}', 'UsersController@index', function($id){});
```

Then how do you check if $id is set

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a default parameter in function:

```php
Route::get('users/{id?}',function($id = null){
   if($id){
      echo $id;
   }else{
      // ...
   }
});
```

Comment: And how would i do it in a controller?

Comment: Same thing, use a default parameter in `index` method

Answer (score 0):

Try to do that simply-

```
/**
 * PAssing parameter through route
 */

Route::get('book/{category}', function($category = null){

    # check the status of category
    if ($category) {

        # show specific category
        $books = Book::where('category', '=', $category);
    } else{

        # otherwise show all books 
        $books = Book::all();
    }


    # Return to view page
    Return View::make('book')
                ->with('books', $books);


});
```

Hope it will work now.

The following articles has very good introduction regarding this issue. Please take a look-
http://tisuchi.com/easy-way-handle-routing-laravel/

Although, you can take a look into official page- http://laravel.com/docs/routing#route-parameters because there is no alternative of official documents.

Comment: You are copy pasting code from http://tisuchi.com/easy-way-handle-routing-laravel/ without proper attribution. You should check [How to reference material written by others](http://stackoverflow.com/help/referencing)

Comment: Thanks. But this is write by myself... so could not be plagiarized...
http://tisuchi.com/easy-way-handle-routing-laravel/